# How get the opposite result of the search pattern?

Tags: c#

In this method,

```
string[] list1 = new DirectoryInfo(HFilepath).GetFiles("Not")
                 .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
                 .Select(f => f.Name)
                 .ToArray();
```

i can get that files name started with like "Not" using `searchPattern`, but i really want the files except the files that does not begin with "NOT".How to do that using `DirectoryInfo` method.

Comment: "*but i really want the files except the files that does not begin with "NOT"*"

So... you want the ones that begin with not? That would equal `GetFiles("Not")` which you already have written there

Comment: Then you are already done since this code does exactly what you ask.

Comment: `.GetFiles()
        .Where(f => !Path.GetFileName(f.Name).StartsWith("NOT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: if its (not[except] not[does not begin with]) the files that begin with "NOT"? <--so take it as one "not"?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have to filter out the files's names manually:

```
  string[] list1 = new DirectoryInfo(HFilepath)
    .GetFiles() 
    .Where(f => !Path 
       .GetFileName(f.Name)
       .StartsWith("NOT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .Where(f => !f.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))
    .Select(f => f.Name)
    .ToArray();
```